# How to open a dialog fragment immediately after new fragment navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a `FragmentA` and want to replace with `FragmentB`. Once navigated to `FragmentB`, I want to immediately open a full screen `DialogFragment` and upon dismissing should show below fragment(`FragmentB`)

I am calling the `DialogFragment` inside `init{}` of `FragmentB`'s `Presenter` class.

The problem here is, I see `FragmentB`'s layout for fraction of seconds until Dialog is opened. The experience should be like,

A -> B immediately open the Dialog fragment without seeing B's layout -> dismiss dialog -> see Fragment B

Any ideas/solution to get above behaviour?thanks

Comment: if you use ViewModel/LiveData, fragment B should not show a UI until the ViewModel pushes a LiveData state indicating what to do; so the 1st thing B's ViewModel will do is push a state that makes Fragment B show the full screen dialog. Upon dismissing of this dialog, (perhaps using an Activity/Shared ViewModel), the state will be show B's layout (which will be below). That would be the "correct" way to ensure the lifecycles are synchronized.

Comment: All that being said, I would not do that. I would have the Activity's view Model (or Fragment's, or shared) have the business logic deciding what/when to show it; the activity or fragment only reacts to this and shows either the dialog or B's layout.